# VSCode esp-idf wont link my component folder to project

Tags: cmake, esp32, esp-idf

I'm trying to create new a folder, where I will keep my components, I already have default components folder (components), but I want to use two or more folders to keep my files sorted. I tried creating new folder (managed_components), adding files but my main file can't find new components folder

[image]

I have read, that I need to update my CMakeLists.txt file by adding `EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS` command, but I don't know how it works and can't find any information how to use it, what exactly should I do to tell my  main.c file, that there are other component folders in this project and how to link them?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `managed_components` directory is used by the [IDF Component Manager](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-component-manager.html), so you should come up with a different name.

Secondly, consider if you really need multiple component directories. Do you know that you can have subdirectory for each component inside `components` directory? For example:

```
cd components/
idf.py create-component new_component
```

Finally, if you do want to add extra component directories, then edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the root of your project and add a line like so:

```
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS my_extra_components)
```

See this example [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/4c98bee8a4417d92a387ef2416be14ff1fdfa92a/examples/peripherals/i2c/i2c_tools/CMakeLists.txt).